# How to constraint input type and output type to be the same?

Tags: type-safety, dependent-type, idris

I am going through Type driven development with Idris from Manning. An example is given that teaches how to restrict a function to a given type in a family of types. We have `Vehicle` type that uses `PowerSource` that is either `Pedal` or `Petrol` and we need to write a function `refill` that typechecks only for vehicles that use petrol as their powersource.

The below code works, but does not guarantee that refilling a `Car` will produce a `Car` and not a `Bus`. How do I need to change the signature of the `refill` function to only allow producing `Car` when given a `Car` and producing `Bus` when given `Bus`?

```
data PowerSource
  = Pedal
  | Petrol

data Vehicle : PowerSource -> Type 
  where
    Bicycle : Vehicle Pedal
    Car : (fuel : Nat) -> Vehicle Petrol
    Bus : (fuel : Nat) -> Vehicle Petrol

refuel : Vehicle Petrol -> Nat -> Vehicle Petrol
refuel (Car fuel) x        = Car (fuel + x)
refuel (Bus fuel) x        = Bus (fuel + x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by introducing new `VehicleType` data type and by adding one more parameter to `Vehicle` like this:

```
data VehicleType = BicycleT | CarT | BusT

data Vehicle : PowerSource -> VehicleType -> Type 
  where
    Bicycle :                 Vehicle Pedal  BicycleT
    Car     : (fuel : Nat) -> Vehicle Petrol CarT
    Bus     : (fuel : Nat) -> Vehicle Petrol BusT
```

You should somehow encode in type difference between constructors. If you want more type safety you need to add more information to types. Then you can use it to implement `refuel` function:

```
refuel : Vehicle Petrol t -> Nat -> Vehicle Petrol t
refuel (Car fuel) x        = Car (fuel + x)
refuel (Bus fuel) x        = Bus (fuel + x)
```

Replacing

```
refuel (Car fuel) x        = Car (fuel + x)
```

with

```
refuel (Car fuel) x        = Bus (fuel + x)
```

leads to next type error:

```
Type checking ./Fuel.idr
Fuel.idr:14:8:When checking right hand side of refuel with expected type
        Vehicle Petrol CarT

Type mismatch between
        Vehicle Petrol BusT (Type of Bus fuel)
and
        Vehicle Petrol CarT (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                BusT
        and
                CarT
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to do what you want externally. It might be an option when you cannot change the original type, e.g. if it comes from a library. Or if you do not want to clutter your type with too many extra indices which you might want to add to state more properties.

Let us reuse the `VehicleType` type introduced by @Shersh:

```
data VehicleType = BicycleT | CarT | BusT
```

Now, let's define a function which tells us which constructor was used to construct a vehicle. It allows us to state our property quit consice:

```
total
vehicleType : Vehicle t -> VehicleType
vehicleType Bicycle = BicycleT
vehicleType (Car _) = CarT
vehicleType (Bus _) = BusT
```

And now we can say that `refuel` preserves the type of a vehicle:

```
total
refuelPreservesVehicleType : vehicleType (refuel v x) = vehicleType v
refuelPreservesVehicleType {v = (Car _)} = Refl
refuelPreservesVehicleType {v = (Bus _)} = Refl
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This approach with external function trick is really nice!